# What input event can I fire when someone clicks on a custom button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have this plot-

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv")

# create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add surface trace
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale="Viridis"))

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
    width=800,
    height=900,
    autosize=False,
    margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
    template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
    aspectmode="manual"
)

# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type = "buttons",
            direction = "left",
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args=["type", "surface"],
                    label="3D Surface",
                    method="restyle"
                ),
                dict(
                    args=["type", "heatmap"],
                    label="Heatmap",
                    method="restyle"
                )
            ]),
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.11,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)

# Add annotation
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="Trace type:", showarrow=False,
                             x=0, y=1.08, yref="paper", align="left")
    ]
)

fig.show()
```

I want to update the chart whenever someone clicks on either of the two buttons. I need to connect the update code to some event. If it was changing the x-axis, for example, I could use the relayout_data event. Is there any event that gets fired when someone clicks a custom button that I can tie to an Input() callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good news and bad news:

The bad news: There is no straightforward tweak for this and you might need to use `javascript` too.

The good news: Here are two options to tackle the requirement:

##### Option#1: javascript

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv")

# create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add surface trace
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale="Viridis"))

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
  width=800,
  height=900,
  autosize=False,
  margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
  template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
  aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
  aspectmode="manual"
)

# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(
  updatemenus=[
    dict(
      type = "buttons",
      direction = "left",
      buttons=list([
        dict(
          args=["type", "surface"],
          label="3D Surface",
          method="restyle",
          execute=False
        ),
        dict(
          args=["type", "heatmap"],
          label="Heatmap",
          method="restyle",
          execute=False
        )
      ]),
      pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
      showactive=True,
      x=0.11,
      xanchor="left",
      y=1.1,
      yanchor="top"
    ),
  ]
)

# Add annotation
fig.update_layout(
  annotations=[
    dict(text="Trace type:", showarrow=False,
               x=0, y=1.08, yref="paper", align="left")
  ]
)

fig.show()
```

Note the part where we add `execute=False`. This allows the JS function `plotly_buttonclicked` to act as a customizable callback function for the component's click.

As per [this documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.layout.updatemenu.html):

> property `execute` When true, the API method is executed. When false,
> all other behaviors are the same and command execution is skipped.
> This may be useful when hooking into, for example, the
> `plotly_buttonclicked` method and executing the API command manually
> without losing the benefit of the `updatemenu` automatically binding to
> the state of the plot through the specification of method and args.
>
> The `execute` property must be specified as a `bool` (either `True`, or
> `False`)
>
> Returns Return type `bool`

##### Option #2: residing to `dash`:

Since `plotly` is built on `dash`, you can go back and forth between them. Here is how you should do it:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, ctx
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# load dataset
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/volcano.csv")

# create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add surface trace
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale="Viridis"))

# Update plot sizing
fig.update_layout(
  width=800,
  height=900,
  autosize=False,
  margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0),
  template="plotly_white",
)

# Update 3D scene options
fig.update_scenes(
  aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7),
  aspectmode="manual"
)

# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(
  updatemenus=[
    dict(
      type = "buttons",
      direction = "left",
      buttons=list([
        dict(
          args=["type", "surface"],
          label="3D Surface",
          method="restyle",
          execute=False
        ),
        dict(
          args=["type", "heatmap"],
          label="Heatmap",
          method="restyle",
          execute=False
        )
      ]),
      pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
      showactive=True,
      x=0.11,
      xanchor="left",
      y=1.1,
      yanchor="top"
    ),
  ]
)

# Add annotation
fig.update_layout(
  annotations=[
    dict(text="Trace type:", showarrow=False,
               x=0, y=1.08, yref="paper", align="left")
  ]
)

# Instead of loading the figure relying on `plotly`'s engine, how about embedding it as a `dash` object:
#fig.show()
dash_fig = dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
  html.Label('Trace Type:', id='ttype'),
  html.Button('Surface', id='surf', n_clicks=0),
  html.Button('Heatmap', id='heat', n_clicks=0),
  dash_fig])


@app.callback(
  Output('ttype', 'children'),
  Input(component_id='surf', component_property='n_clicks'),
  Input(component_id='heat', component_property='n_clicks'))
def click_callback(n1,n2):
  return f'{ctx.triggered_id}:{n1}:{n2}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Note how now we have the callback function `click_callback`.

Remains the task to reimplement the graph change code since it has to be done manually now.

Comment: Great answer! It should qualify to receive the bounty.